# ERROR deleting item from database using confirm box

Tags: php, javascript

I have the following code which retrieves items from my DB and displays them in a table. The file is manage-products.php.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
       echo '</tr>';
       echo ' <td class="product"><a href="manage-products-2.php">'.$row[1].'</a></td>';
       echo'<td class="quantity">'.$row[5].'</td>';
       echo '<td class="item_price">'.$row[4].'</td>';
       echo '<td class="item_total">'.$row[6].'</td>';
       echo '<td class="item_unsold"><a href = "manage-products.php?prod = '.$row[0].'" style="color:red">Delete</a></td>';//to delete an item
       echo '</tr>';
}
```

I have the following code (which should be executed) when the DELETE link is clicked (also in manage-products.php)

```
$prodid = $_GET['prod'];

if($prodid != ""){
  echo '<script type="text/javascript"> 
  var r = window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this product") ;
  if(r == true){
    $ . post ( "manage-products.php" ,  { result : r });
  }
  </script>';
  $delete = $_POST['result'];
  if($delete == true){
    $SQL1 = "DELETE FROM tbl_product WHERE id = '$prodid'";
    $result1 = mysql_query($SQL1);
  }
}
```

When i click delete it says undefined index:prod. Please where is my error. Thanks

Comment: What does `print_r($_GET);` display ?

Comment: You need to get a much better understanding of server side vs client side.

Comment: please do not use user provided data directly in an sql query without using some sort of escaping feature, ideally you shouldn't even be using mysql_* functions anymore, but if you have to, at least make sure you use mysql_real_escape_string() on $prodid in your query

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @RelevantUsername it prints Array([prod_] => 20)

Answer (score 0):

Do the confirm before reload, and delete the product during reload if it's happens, you'll be more performant.

Like this on the delete link :

```
echo '<td class="item_unsold"><a href = "manage-products.php?prod='.$row[0].'" style="color:red" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this product ?')">Delete</a></td>';//to delete an item
```

then when reload :

```
$prodid = $_GET['prod'];

if($prodid != "" && is_numeric($prodid)){
    $SQL1 = "DELETE FROM tbl_product WHERE id = '$prodid'";
    $result1 = mysql_query($SQL1);
  }
}
```

Do not forget to sanitize variable (check numeric type) before delete ;)

**EDIT :**

Replace `manage-products.php?prod = '.$row[0]` by `manage-products.php?prod='.$row[0]`

Comment: Thanks but it still does nothing as before. It just prints undefined index: prod.

Comment: print_r($row) and see what's contained in the 0 index

Comment: remove space in the called url, I've edited my post... Retry and it should works

Comment: i did print_r($row) contains the ids, so does print_r($_GET). I also removed the space but nothing changed.